# Certificate not found for xConnect

Tags: xconnect, certificate

Environment: Sitecore 9.0.2 + SXA in XP0 on VM

What I am trying: I am trying to enable xConnect on my VM.

What I did: I followed the steps provided in [this blog](https://chrisperks.co/2018/03/13/enable-xconnect-on-a-local-developer-machine/) but was unable to get it up.

Log: Under xConnect, I have no log corresponding to it. Under my Sitecore Client, I have the following log entry:

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: The certificate was not found.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifier.Process(HttpClientHandler handler)
```

What are my findings till now:
I have validated my settings and have the following points in order:

1. thumbprint of certificate in the certificate manager and both the
   configs of xConnect
2. The certificate is not expired.
3. On browsing the xConnect site with https, I do not see any warning or error.

Where should I look further?
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I wrote about this troubleshoot](https://coveoticore.wordpress.com/2019/02/19/how-to-fix-a-certificate-issue-on-a-sitecore-9-1-instance/) a few weeks ago, but here are the main steps:

**1. Make sure you have the rights certificates on the right places:**

**Local Computer Certificates**

- Trusted Root Certification Authorities:

DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert with private key

- Personal:

One certificate for your xConnect website issued by DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert

**Current User Certificates**

- Trusted Root Certification Authorities:

DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert with private key

- Personal:

DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert with private key

**2. Make sure you have the right xConnect certificate thumbprint here:**

- .sc\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config
- .xconnect\App_Config\AppSettings.config
- .xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config
- .xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\ProcessingEngine\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config

**3. Make sure you have the right certificate on IIS for xConnect website**

[image]

**4. Make sure the xConnect website ISS App user has the right access on your certificate**

[image]

Comment: I was not able to find .xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\ProcessingEngine\App_Config\ConnectionString.config.
I am on Sitecore Sitecore.NET 9.0.2 (rev. 180604). What I have is IndexWorker and its AppSetting.config or ConnectionString.config does not have a Thumbprint.

Comment: @Renuka in case of scaled environment path can be different. If processing is set as independent node the path would be 
`.processingEngine\App_Data\jobs\continous\ProcessingEngine\AppConfig\ConnectionStrings.config`  
Where **.processingEngine** is directory where that node is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Check the client certificate thumbprint mentioned in the ConnectionStrings.config is installed in the web server